# Extracting content from entire html code with javascript and ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

I need to create a form which has an input of a URL and as an output it shows me some specific tags of the html page.

after a little reaserch I did understand that i need to use Ajax, which im not really familiar with it.

I wanted to know if i have some limitation about some privacy issue to gain the html code, or is it possibile to apply this to all type of websites or just local html files.

Other question is, how to test this form local? Now i'm having some issues with XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: You need to learn about AJAX, and in particular about the Same-Origin Policy.

Comment: Ajax has a lot of extra options and it is easy to learn. Check out content type. Html is only allowed from same origin. Jquery can be downloaded and used locally as well.